# Use of underscore in function call with Try parameters

Tags: scala, scala-placeholder-syntax

I'm trying to understand particular use of underscore in Scala. And following piece of code I cannot understand

```
class Test[T, S] {
  def f1(f: T => S): Unit = f2(_ map f)

  def f2(f: Try[T] => Try[S]): Unit = {}
}
```

How is the `_` treated in this case? How is the `T=>S` becomes `Try[T]=>Try[S]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are reading it wrongly. Look at the type of `f2(Try[T] => Try[S]):Unit`.

Then looking into f1 we have `f: T => S`.

The `_` in value position desugars to `f2(g => g map f)`.

Let's see what we know so far:

1. `f2(Try[T] => Try[S]):Unit`
2. `f: T => S`
3. `f2(g => g map f)`

Give 1. and 3. we can infer that the type of `g` has to be `Try[T]`. map over `Try[T]` takes `T => Something`, in case `f` which is `T => S`, in which case Something is `S`.

It may seem a bit hard to read now, but once you learn to distinguish between type and value position readin this type of code becomes trivial.

Another thing to notice `def f2(f: Try[T] => Try[S]): Unit = {}` is quite uninteresting and may be a bit detrimental in solving your particular question.

I'd try to solve this like that: first forget the class you created. Now implement this (replace the `???` with a useful implementation):

```
object P1 { 
  def fmap[A, B](A => B): Try[A] => Try[B] = ??? 
}
```

For bonus points use the `_` as the first char in your implementation.